# How to timeout for specific systemd unit?

Tags: systemd, bind, bind9

Is there a way to change timeout for specific systemd unit? I'm okay with the default 90s, except for bind9; we serve tens of thousands of zones so bind9 needs a few minutes to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a [`TimeoutStartSec`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#TimeoutStartSec=) entry in the `[Service]` section. Assuming your service is called `bind9`, run

```
sudo systemctl edit bind9
```

and add the override:

```
[Service]
TimeoutStartSec=5min
```